# Can someone please help me understand this command?

Tags: android, sd-card, dm-crypt

```
dmsetup create crypt1 --table "0 `blockdev --getsize /dev/sdb2` crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 <Put the 16-byte hex key here> 0 /dev/sdb2 0"
```

I got it from step 6 of the first answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage).

I am trying to view the files on an android adopted SD card.

The card suddenly stopped working on my phone and I'm now trying to retrieve my files before I press on "forget" to unmount it from my phone and go back. To using my phone normally on it's Internal memory.

Comment: consider copying the entire thing with `ddrescue` first before you experiment on possibly faulty SD card

Answer (score 1):

It creates a Device Mapper target, manually.

For the meaning of these parameters, see [DM-Crypt on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/device-mapper/dm-crypt.html)

> ```
> <cipher> <key> <iv_offset> <device path> <offset> [<#opt_params> <opt_params>]
> ```

So in your case, the mapping covers range 0 through `blockdev --getsize /dev/sdb2` (i.e. the entire device), type `crypt`, cipher `aes-cbc-essiv:sha256`, key `<Put the 16-byte hex key here>`, IV offset `0`, device path `/dev/sdb2`, offset `0`.

The not-so-manual way to create the same mapping is with `cryptsetup`:

```
cryptsetup open \
    --type plain \
    --cipher aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 \
    --key-size 128 \
    --key-file your/binary/key \
    /dev/loop0 \
    crypt1
```

Results in:

```
# dmsetup table crypt1 --showkeys
0 134215680 crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 08d827d5b10dc5816e5edddca6fe0e30 0 7:0 0
```

That's just how these Device Mapper targets look like.

Whether you use `cryptsetup` to create it, or `dmsetup create ...`, or something else, is a matter of taste.

It will only work if the cipher mode and key is correct. Be careful not to write to the resulting device.

Comment: OK. First of.. THANK YOU! 2nd, I might be a little in over my head on this. The above is a cmd I copied from the linked source. What in that cmd might need to change depending on my particular device/setting/circumstance? And yeah, I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 LTS live USB.

Comment: @Daylark impossible for me to answer since you never specified your device and I don't know Android that well, so maybe you need to ask a more specific question on Android SE...?

Comment: @Daylark basically the only way for this to work is if you know the correct device name, cipher and key, and the device itself is actually encrypted this way and not any other way. If any variable is off, you get the wrong results. If the encryption is done differently, you need a different approach.

Comment: The encryption (Put the 16-byte hex key here) part is convered. I have the encryption key. Correct me if I'm wrong but the specs of my phone, isn't that irrelevant since I'm just working on the SD card?